# Avoid antialising of R plots in iPython Notebook

Tags: python, r, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In iPython Notebook (with rmagic extension) the plots don't look crisp. They are antialised. I have tried different combinations of width and height for example `%R -w 600 -h 400 plot(1)` without success.

How can I make the R plots look better, as the matplotlib ones?

Example of R Plot:

[image: Plot using R magic]

Example of Matplotlib:

[image: Plot using Matplotlib]

Comment: You could try to generate SVG files instead of PNG files -- but I do not have the impression that rmagic provides this option.

Comment: Generating SVG is breaking as soon as there is more than one plot in a notebook (see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1866). This might be the reason why rmagic is using PNGs by default.

Answer (score 0):

The git version of IPython's rmagic extension ( https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/extensions/rmagic.py#L380) has the option to specify image resolution (e.g., `%R -r 96 plot(7)`). However, the `needs_local_scope` decorator causes the calls to `%R` to fail. A quick hack that seems to work more or less (setting plot resolution works and haven't seen anything break yet) would be to uncomment it on line `401`.

**Before (72dpi)**:

[image: 72dpi]

**After (96 dpi)**:

[image: 96dpi]